# Hadoop: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Thanks for your help first. In the map class, I instantiated another class WebPageToText.
My first question:
will the print in the map class appear when running the code in Hadoop?
2nd question:
Please help me with this error.

I keep getting this problem:

```
    14/04/02 20:39:35 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
    14/04/02 20:39:36 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
    14/04/02 20:39:36 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
    14/04/02 20:39:36 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
    14/04/02 20:39:36 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local1947041074_0001
    14/04/02 20:39:36 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
    14/04/02 20:39:36 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1947041074_0001_m_000000_0
    14/04/02 20:39:36 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
    14/04/02 20:39:36 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@1cf7491
    14/04/02 20:39:36 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/usr/local/hadoop/project/input1/url.txt:0+68
    14/04/02 20:39:36 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
    14/04/02 20:39:36 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
    14/04/02 20:39:36 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
    14/04/02 20:39:36 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
    14/04/02 20:39:36 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
    14/04/02 20:39:36 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1947041074_0001
    java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
        ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/l3s/boilerpipe/BoilerpipeProcessingException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:810)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:855)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:881)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getMapperClass(JobConf.java:968)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.l3s.boilerpipe.BoilerpipeProcessingException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
        ... 23 more
    14/04/02 20:39:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
    14/04/02 20:39:37 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local1947041074_0001
    14/04/02 20:39:37 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
    14/04/02 20:39:37 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: NA
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
        at webPageToTxt.ConfMain.run(ConfMain.java:33)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at webPageToTxt.ConfMain.main(ConfMain.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

The conf class:
    package webPageToTxt;

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;


public class ConfMain extends Configured implements Tool{

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

          //creating a JobConf object and assigning a job name for identification purposes
          JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), ConfMain.class);
          conf.setJobName("webpage to txt");

          //Setting configuration object with the Data Type of output Key and Value
          conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
          conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

          //Providing the mapper and reducer class names
          conf.setMapperClass(WebPageToTxtMapper.class);
          conf.setReducerClass(WebPageToTxtReducer.class);

          //the hdfs input and output directory to be fetched from the command line
          FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]));
          FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

          JobClient.runJob(conf);
          System.out.println("configuration is done");
          return 0;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new ConfMain(),args);
         System.exit(res);
    }
}
```

The map class

```
package webPageToTxt;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

import de.l3s.boilerpipe.BoilerpipeProcessingException;


public class WebPageToTxtMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>
{
         private Text url = new Text();
         private Text wordList = new Text();
      //map method that performs the tokenizer job and framing the initial key value pairs
      public void map(Text key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
      {
            try {
                System.out.println("Prepare to get into webpage");
//              String val = WebPageToTxt.webPageToTxt("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun\nhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth");

                String val = WebPageToTxt.webPageToTxt(value.toString());
                System.out.println("Webpage main function implemented");

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(val);
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                      // process the line
                    String[] arr = line.split("`", 2);
                    url.set(arr[0]);
                    wordList.set(line);
                    output.collect(url, wordList);
                }
                scanner.close();
            } catch (BoilerpipeProcessingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print statements in mapper or reduce method will not appear in main job output, for viewing the output use Jobtracker webUI

Choose the `correct Jobid` from Jobid Column -> Click on `Map/Reduce` from  Kind Column -> Click on `respective Map/Reduce` task -> Click on `All` Tasklog clolumn

Since you are using the class de.l3s.boilerpipe.BoilerpipeProcessingException in mapper method you need to make this class available in distributed manner, for that if you are exeuting this application using hadoop command make use of -libjars Generic option
 (Need to implement ToolRunner Class) or Simply pack the jar containing the class `de.l3s.boilerpipe.BoilerpipeProcessingException` along with the Main jar itself.