# Hadoop: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/parsers/AbstractSAXParser

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

My previous problem was posted here:

[Hadoop: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825888/hadoop-java-lang-exception-java-lang-runtimeexception-error-in-configuring-ob)

Then I followed the advice and package all the jar files into one and the first problem is solved. 
Please reference the previous post for source code. Thanks in advance.
But new problem comes as:

```
14/04/03 13:47:39 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
14/04/03 13:47:40 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
14/04/03 13:47:40 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
14/04/03 13:47:40 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/04/03 13:47:40 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local1748858601_0001
14/04/03 13:47:40 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
14/04/03 13:47:40 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1748858601_0001_m_000000_0
14/04/03 13:47:40 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
14/04/03 13:47:40 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@c943d1
14/04/03 13:47:40 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/usr/local/hadoop/project/input1/url.txt:0+68
14/04/03 13:47:40 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
14/04/03 13:47:40 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
14/04/03 13:47:40 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
14/04/03 13:47:40 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
Prepare to get into webpage
14/04/03 13:47:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/04/03 13:47:43 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
14/04/03 13:47:43 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1748858601_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/parsers/AbstractSAXParser
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xerces/parsers/AbstractSAXParser
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeSAXInput.getTextDocument(BoilerpipeSAXInput.java:51)
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ExtractorBase.getText(ExtractorBase.java:69)
    at de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ExtractorBase.getText(ExtractorBase.java:87)
    at webPageToTxt.WebPageToTxt.webPageString(WebPageToTxt.java:82)
    at webPageToTxt.WebPageToTxt.multiWebPageString(WebPageToTxt.java:126)
    at webPageToTxt.WebPageToTxt.webPageToTxt(WebPageToTxt.java:40)
    at webPageToTxt.WebPageToTxtMapper.map(WebPageToTxtMapper.java:27)
    at webPageToTxt.WebPageToTxtMapper.map(WebPageToTxtMapper.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    ... 29 more
14/04/03 13:47:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local1748858601_0001
14/04/03 13:47:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
14/04/03 13:47:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: NA
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
    at webPageToTxt.ConfMain.run(ConfMain.java:33)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at webPageToTxt.ConfMain.main(ConfMain.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add all the jars which you are using outside the jar in which your driver & map reduce code resides so that they are available to the mapper at runtime.

I went through the link you provided. Though packaging the other classes as a part of the Map Reduce jar works. This is not always possible. As you see you are here using xerces for which you need to include xerces-impl.jar.

A better approach is to add these jars to DistributedCache.

`DistributedCache.addArchiveToClassPath(new Path("HDFS Path"), job);`

You can keep the jars in HDFS. So the solution is to add xerces jar.